# Service returning data but can't subscribe

Tags: angular

In my component.ts I am calling a function from my service class which retrieves data from my backend rest api. When logging the result I successfully retrieved the data but when trying to subscribe to it in my component nothing happens

```
vehicles: VehicleDto[] = [];

  constructor(private myService: MyService) {

    console.log(this.myService.getVehicles());
    console.log("Before Service call");
    this.myService.getVehicles().subscribe((result: any[]) => {

      console.log("service called");
      this.vehicles = result;
      console.log(this.vehicles); //this is console for vehicles     
    });
    console.log("after service call");
  }
```

In my service class:

```
 getVehicles() : Observable<VehicleDto[]> {

    let resultSubject: AsyncSubject<VehicleDto[]> = new AsyncSubject();
    let httpOptions = this.kecloakService.buildHeaderWithToken();
    this.configurationService.loadNetworkConfiguration(false).subscribe((config: NetworkConfiguration) => {

      if (config) {
        this.http.get(config.getHostUrl + this.url + "getVehicles", httpOptions)
        .subscribe((entities: VehicleDto[]) => {
          let results: VehicleDto[] = [];
          for(let entity of entities) {
            results.push(entity);
          }
          resultSubject.next(results);
          resultSubject.complete;
        });
      }
    });
    return resultSubject;
  }
```

This is the result I get in the console
[image]

As you can see I do get the array back, but inside the subscribe the result never gets logged or assigned to vehicles.

Comment: Use promise instead.

Comment: @MalavanRockzz why using a promise instead of an Observable ? https://medium.com/javascript-everyday/javascript-theory-promise-vs-observable-d3087bc1239a

Comment: You also return AsyncSubject but your signature say: Observable<VehicleDto[]>

Comment: First of all he should get rid of his nested subscriptions.

Comment: @Yvan I believe Malavan Rockzz means async-await when he says Promises

Comment: @MoxxiManagarm  Probably :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an Observable and should work :

```
  getVehicles(): Observable<VehicleDto[]> {
    let httpOptions = this.kecloakService.buildHeaderWithToken();
    return new Observable((obs => {
      this.configurationService.loadNetworkConfiguration(false).subscribe((config: NetworkConfiguration) => {
        if (config) {
          this.http.get(config.getHostUrl + this.url + "getVehicles", httpOptions)
            .subscribe(
              (entities: VehicleDto[]) => {
                let results: VehicleDto[] = [];
                for (let entity of entities) {
                  results.push(entity);
                }
                obs.next(results);
                obs.complete();
              }
            );
        }
      });
    }));
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because of the asynchronous nature. Please inform yourself about callsbacks. When you have trouble to understand callbacks, then feel free to use async-await.
Get rid of your nested subscriptions!!

```
// Variant A+B
vehicles: VehicleDto[];
// Veriant C
vehicles$: Observable<VehicleDto[]>;

constructor(private myService: MyService) {
    // Variant A: async-await
    this.vehicles = await this.myService.getVehiclesPromised();

    // Variant B: callback (least recommended, do not forget to unsubscribe!)
    // this.myService.getVehicles().subscribe((result: VehicleDto[]) => {
    // this.vehicles = result;
    // });

    // Variant C: Observable (use async pipe in template to access data)
    //this.vehicles$ = this.myService.getVehicles();
}

async getVehiclesPromised(): Promise<VehicleDto[]> {
    const httpOptions = this.kecloakService.buildHeaderWithToken();

    const config: NetworkConfiguration = await this.configurationService.loadNetworkConfigurationPromised(false);
    return config ? await this.http.get(config.getHostUrl + this.url + "getVehicles", httpOptions).toPromise() : [];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could change the last line to:

```
return resultSubject.asObservable();
```

and the service will return the object with type `Observable<VehicleDto[]>`, you are currently returning the type `AsyncSubject`;